# Ayuda con un Form Html y Php

Tags: php, html

llevo días dandole vueltas y no veo el error. Ya estoy cegado y no se que más probar. A ver si alguien me puede echar una mano. Tiene que ser cualquier pego.

Tengo un formulario HTML que carga un select desde un php que lee de Mysql. Tengo este código en otras partes del código y me funciona perfectamente. solo cambia la tabla desde la que lee.

Cuando lo ejecuto, me carga el HTML y cuando llega al select, no se carga y deja de ejecutar el código, quedando en blanco todo el formulario que hya debajo de él.

Os pongo el Código:

```
<form id="formAfi" name="FormnAfi" method="post">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr style="height: 35px;">
                    <th colspan="2"><label><span>Introduce los datos</span></label></th>
                </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Num. Afiliado<span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="NumAfi" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre<span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Nombre" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>DNI<span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="dni" required/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Cuota</label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="impCuota"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="formaP">Forma Pago</label></td>
                    <td><?php include("../recursos/formasPagoSelect.php"); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Fecha Alta</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="alta" value="<?php echo date(); ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Observaciones</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" cols="40" rows="5" name="observaciones"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><button align="middle" class="formButtom" name="guardar" onClick="guardarAfi()" >Guardar</button></td></tr>
                <br><br>
                <div id="status"></div>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Este sería el formasPagoSelect.php

```
<?php
include "../class/tFormasPago.php";

$oFormasPago = new tFormasPago(1, 0, 1, 1);
$respuesta = $oFormasPago->selectForma();


echo $respuesta;
?>
```

y este el tFormasPago.php

```
<?php

include 'tMySQL.php';


class tFormasPago
{
public $forma = '';
public $numero = '';

public $bFlag = false;  

public $fila;
public $cuantos = 1;

public function tFormasPago()
{   
    $this->bFlag = true;
    //$this->GetUser();
}

public function selectForma()
{
    $oMySQL = new tMySQL();

    if ($oMySQL->bConnect)
    {
        $cSQL ="SELECT COUNT(*) AS cuantos FROM formas_pago";   
        $this->fila = $oMySQL->countQuery($cSQL);
        $this->cuantos = $this->fila['cuantos'];

        $query = "SELECT idForma, nombre FROM formas_pago ORDER BY idForma"; 
        $result = $oMySQL->GetQuery($query);

        $response ='<select  id="formaP" name="formaP">';
        $i=0;
        while( $i <= $this->cuantos ) {
            $response .= '<option value="'.$result[$i]['nombre'].'">'.$result[$i]['nombre'].'</option>';
            $i++;
        }
        $response .= '</select>';

    }

    $oMySQL->Close();   
    return $response;
} 
}

?>
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas gracias por anticipado.
Un saludo.

---

He descubierto que el problema no esta en el include("../recursos/formasPagoSelect.php");, sino en el otro include que hago anteriormente en el código. Es como si algo se quedase abierto y este no se ejecutase. Cuando elimino el include anterior, que es idem a este pero que consulta a otra tabla, este funciona, y si pongo otro después, el de después no funciona hasta que no quito este.

Ha ver si con este aporte alguien me echa una mano, por que me trae loco.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Buenas, en primer lugar debes comprobar que las consultas te devuelven los que tu quieres, si te devuelve lo que quieres, haz un var_dump($response) y posteala y seguimos al siguiente paso

Comment: El resultado es correcto, cuando ejecuto el formasPagoSelect.php, me devuelve un select funcional. El resultado que me ha devuelto el var_dump, es string(232) "<select id="formaP" name="formaP"><option value="BANCO">BANCO</option><option value="NOMINA">NOMINA</option><option value="DISCO CTA">DISCO CTA</option><option value="DISCO CGT">DISCO CGT</option><option value=""></option></select>"

Comment: @Avielo estás incluyendo un fichero que define una clase. Puede que estés recibiendo un error al cargarlo una segunda vez. Prueba dos cosas: primero añade `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al principio de tu fichero para ver si te muestra algún error. También prueba a incluir el fichero usando [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php) en lugar de `include`.

Comment: Buenas tardes Alvaro, ese era el problema. Perdón por la tardanza en contestar. Dentro del include se cargaba otra clase con los parámetros de mysql, al cargar el segundo include que también tenia dentro el include de mysql generaba el error. Se soluciono como bien decías con el include_once. Un saludo y muchas gracias.